# Why does Python behave so absurdly when dealing with numbers with decimal points?

Tags: memory-management, python, data-types

[image] r1 and r2 both are assigned 0.05 initially. If r1 is incremented by 0.01 in this way "r1 = r1 +0.01" we have 0.060000000000000005 as answer not 0.06.

Comment: It's floating-point arithmetic. Its not exact, it is rounded. Typically a 53 bit mantissa.

Comment: https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf

Answer (score 4):

This is the foundation of computer arithmetic, when dealing with fractional values. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic.)

The key reason is that numbers are represented in the binary base rather than decimal. Though $0.06$ is a short number in your world, it cannot be represented exactly by a computer.

But there is nothing shocking: try and expand $1/3$ in the decimal notation, and tell us when you are done... :-)

---

The next topic to know about is "rounding": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding.

Answer (score 3):

As @gnashed729 remarks, this is how [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) works, and it is not specific to Python.

It is all clearly [explained in the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

- Python (like most programming languages) interprets a number such as `0.3` as a floating-point number, using the computer's built-in support for floating-point arithmetic, if present;
- computers represent floating-point number as binary fractions, not decimal fractions;
- decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions; for instance, `0.1` (decimal) is `0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...` (binary) (this example is from the Python manual);
- as a consequence, you already have a rounding error once you write the number `0.3` down; more rounding errors will occur once you start to do arithmetic with these numbers.

To calculate with exact decimal fractions, you may want to use [the `decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).